# counting cells with only special characters R

Tags: r, count

I have a data.frame as below. I would like to get a list of cells that dont have even a single number or a-to-z and their frequency. How could I do that? In case of below data I want a  table. In the table's first column i will have * and . These second column will show frequency of those values (1 and 2 respectively). "a*" and "21.9" wont appear because they contain at least one number or a-z

```
sm <- matrix(c(51,".",22,"*","a*","21.9",".",22,9),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
smdf<-as.data.frame(sm)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. `apply(smdf,1, function(x) !grepl('[a-z0-9]',x))` will give you a matrix that will tell you for each entry of `smdf` whether it contains at least one of a-z or 0-9. I don't understand the second step. You want a count of cells that contain `*` or `.`. What about a cell that contains both? And are you concerned with special characters in general or just these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this provide what you are looking for?

```
require(plyr)
sm <- matrix(c(51,".",22,"*","a*","21.9",".",22,9),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
count(sm[!grepl("[[:alnum:]]", sm)])

  x freq
1 *    1
2 .    2
```

If you want to also exclude the NA and spaces, you can easily just add the appropriate conditions to the filter.  As a side note, I am fairly certain a more elegant regex could solve this without the extra parameters but my regex skills are in progress.  Will update if I manage to figure out such a thing.

```
sm <- matrix(c(51,".",22,"*","a*","21.9",".",22,9, " ", NA, 13),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
count(sm[!grepl("[[:alnum:]]", sm) & !is.na(sm) & sm != " "])

  x freq
1 *    1
2 .    2
```

However, if there is a specific list of characters you wish to count you can always make a vector of the characters and count only those.  This doesn't require the extra 'space' and 'NA' components.

```
sm <- matrix(c(51,".",22,"*","a*","21.9",".",22,9, " ", NA, 13),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
x <- unlist(strsplit("*~!@#$%^&(){}_+:\"<>?,./;'[]-=", split=""))
count(sm[sm %in% x])

  x freq
1 *    1
2 .    2
```

Comment: Yes, the output is correct. Would it be possible to provide a brief an explanation of how it works?

Comment: @user2543622, it is using the [regular expressions used in R](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html).  The `[[:alnum:]]` selects all containing alphanumeric characters with the `grepl` function.  By not selecting (`!grepl(...)`) from the original matrix and finally counting the remaining with the nice count function from the plyr package.

Comment: Make sure this does what you want it to when one of the entries in `sm` is `'*.'` or `'**'`

Comment: I ran the above solution on a data.frame and I didnt get required result. Therefore I transformed the data.frame to matrix and it worked :). But it also printed out two entries " "blank values and "<NA>"..any idea why?

Comment: A space isn't an alphanumeric character. As far as the solution is concerned it's a "special character. As for the <NA>, does your data frame contain NAs?